# Can electrons fly off a conductor?

Tags: electricity, electrons, superconductivity

This is probably a stupid question, but what if you made an electron flow through a superconductor so that the electrons build up speed flowing through the wire, and then cut the wire.  Would the momentum of the electrons cause them to fly off the wire?  If not, what would happen and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drift velocities in metals are low, also in superconductors, typically less than 1 mm/s. But self-induction may cause a spark if you cut the circuit. And that does not depend on superconductivity.

Comment: Another way electrons can leave a conductor is via thermionic emission, where electrons flow from the hot cathode to the anode in a vacuum tube (valve). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission